# load an xml asset in actionscript without events

Tags: xml, file, flash, actionscript, assets

I am trying to read an XML asset in actionscript. The examples that I find online all seem to be event driven:

http://www.leebrimelow.com/actionscript-3-quicktip-6-loading-xml/

This seems really heavy-handed for a simple file read. Is there a way that I can do this without breaking up my logic into multiple functions?

Answer (score 1):

If it is by any chance Adobe AIR AS3 you are executing and xml file resides on hard drive then you can call FileStream.open function to open file synchronously and load data.

```
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("abc.xml"), FileMode.READ);
var fileContents:String = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
var theXML:XML = new XML(fileContents);
```

If it's not an AIR and/or you need to load data from network, then you will need to relay on URLLoader and event handling as explained in the URL you provided.

Comment: How do I retrieve an asset that has been compiled into the .swf file?